# How can I use angular component imported from a shared module in another component other than AppComponent

Tags: angular

**Using Angular8**

I have created a module(`ChartsModule`) that exports other components. I could import the module  in `app.module.ts` file and use the templates that are exported in `app.component.html`, however trying the same by creating another component with a module that imports `ChartsModule` does not work.

**ChartsModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PieChartComponent } from './pie-chart/pie-chart.component';
import { LinesChartComponent } from './lines-chart/lines-chart.component';
import { TableChartComponent } from './table-chart/table-chart.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [PieChartComponent,LinesChartComponent,TableChartComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports:[PieChartComponent,LinesChartComponent,TableChartComponent]
})
export class ChartsModule { }
```

Inside the **app.module.ts**

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule,
    XComponent,
    ChartsModule]
```

Using the templates inside **app.component.html;**

```
<app-pie-chart></app-pie-chart>
<app-table-chart></app-table-chart>
```

**QUESTION;**

How can I achieve the same effect by importing `ChartsModule` into component X.
This is what I did; generate component X and add a module that will import `ChartsModule` and then to use the templates inside `x.html`.

**x.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChartsModule } from '../data-charts/charts.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
  // schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})

export class XModule { }
```

**Inside of x.component.html**

```
<app-pie-chart></app-pie-chart>
<app-table-chart></app-table-chart>
```

I get the error;

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'app-pie-chart' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-pie-chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-pie-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Is xComponent declared in your xModule ?

Answer (score 3):

The component `X` must be a member of *some* module. Import `ChartsModule` there.

Comment: I think he did (declaring X Component in X Module), without declaring X component how can he access that component? because he should get an error stating X Component must be declared in your module etc..

Comment: I don't know where X component is declared, but it's not `AppModule` (because it would have access to exports from `ChartsModule`), and it isn't `XModule` (because it has `declarations: []`).

Comment: I did import X component inside app module

Comment: That is unexpected. Every component declared in the same module should have all its imported goodness available. What's the difference between `AppComponent` and `XComponent`?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in your AppModule imports. You **can't** import *components*, only *modules* that **has** components.

In this case you must put your **xComponent** inside the `declarations: []` of your **xModule** for a correct solution.

Anyways, if you want to use components that whitin ChartsModule you should declare your xComponent inside `declarations: []` of any module that has ChartsModule inside his `imports: []`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `XComponent` in `XModule` for the required result.

**x.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChartsModule } from '../data-charts/charts.module';
// Import `XComponent` here.

@NgModule({
  declarations: [XComponent], // Just added reference. 
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
  // schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})

export class XModule { }
```

Comment: I think he did (declaring X Component in X Module), without declaring X component how can he access that component? because he should get an error stating X Component must be declared in your module etc..

Comment: In `x.module.ts`, he imported `ChartsModule`. And according to his description, `XComponent` belongs to `XModule`. Thus `XComponent` should be declared in that module according to my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

This is how got it solved;

I imported XComponent into Xmodule, removed XComponent importation from app.module.ts and imported Xmodule inside app.module.ts;

**xmodule.ts**

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChartsModule } from '../data-charts/charts.module';
import {XComponent} from './x.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [XComponent], 
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
})

export class XModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule,
    Xmodule,
    ]
```